# sudo problem. I can't write my password to terminal

Tags: 14.04, python, password, sudo

so I was installing python on my laptop

```
:~/Desktop/Python-3.5.1$ su root
Password: 
ssu: Authentication failure`
```

It didn't let me wrote my password. so I looked help and found that:

```
gksu nautilus
```

might help. I haven't installed gksu. so i tried to install it but it asked again `sudo` password and the only thing that i could do was press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
My problem is that how do you write your password on terminal.

Comment: It is letting you to write your password, it won't show what you are typing due to security reasons..

Comment: Ok but still it says Authentication failure.  i don't know i should just go to windows XDDDD

Comment: Authentication failure means you have inputted wrong password or the  password for root is locked (which is the default). Why don't you use `sudo -i`?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing `su root`, you should use `sudo` instead, as the root account is not enabled by default in Ubuntu, and will not work. This is why you are getting an "Authentication failure" message.

---

Regarding password entry - it won't show you anything as you type, but, it will accept your password after you press enter. Make sure you entered the right password.

This is a security feature so that someone looking over your shoulder doesn't know how many characters your password has.